# how to connect to database linq

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, connection

In SQL we open connection

```
 conn.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 conn.Close();
```

or

```
 using (conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
     cmd1.Connection = conn;
     conn.Open();
     cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

What is best practice for LINQ to SQL:

```
 DataClassesLinqDataContext dbLinq = new DataClassesLinqDataContext();
```

or

```
 using(DataClassesLinqDataContext dbLinq = new DataClassesLinqDataContext())
 {
      var x = ...
 }
```

Comment: doesnt matter, its the same, linq to sql doesnt connect to db directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, best practise is to dispose of the context to free up the resources it holds so I'd go with the `using ()`

Answer (score 2):

offcourse with using "using" clause, it just ensures the dispose method gets called once it ends its scope. No need to free expensive variables like database connection.